# datatables custom sort condition after search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, datatables

Below is the code snippet. By default after search the result were sorted alphabetically. I want it to sort based on the prefix of my search value.

For example I type `b` then it should sort `bbb then abed` while not `abed then bbb`.

```js
$("#filter-button").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $('#filter-body').slideToggle(100);
});

$("#btnSearch").click(function(e){
  var table = $('#custTable').DataTable();
  var txtCustName = $("#txtCustName").val();

  table
    .columns(1).search(txtCustName)
    .draw();
});

$('#custTable').DataTable({
  responsive: {
    details: {
      type: 'column',
      target: 'tr'
    }
  },
  columnDefs: [
  {
    className: 'control',
    orderable: false,
    targets:   0
  }],
  "dom": 'iti',
  iDisplayLength: -1
});

$('#custTable thead th:first-child').css({'background-image':'none'});

$("#custTable a.cust_id").on('click', function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="filter-container">
  <button class="accordion" id="filter-button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">Filter Customer</button>

  <div id="filter-body" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body filter-body">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3" style="text-align:initial;">
        <div class="filter-group">
        <label for="txtCustName">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtCustName">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="text-align:initial;">
<div class="filter-group">
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btnSearch"><i class="mdi mdi-filter-outline"></i> Search</button>
</div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<table id="custTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable no-footer dtr-column" cellspacing="0" width="100%" aria-describedby="custTable_info" role="grid" style="width: 100%;"><thead>
<tr role="row"><th class="control sorting_asc" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 13px; display: none; background-image: none;" aria-label=""></th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="custTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 74px;" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending">Name</th></tr>
</thead><tbody><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=27">abed</a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=28">accure</a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=29">async</a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=30">bbb</a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=20">john</a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=26">pencil</a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=21">steve</a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="even">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=25">taylor</a></td>
</tr><tr role="row" class="odd">
<td class="control sorting_1" style="display: none;"></td>
<td><a class="cust_id" href="customer-detail.php?id=24">zack bro</a></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Please reduce your example to a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't believe that such much HTML is required to understand the problem. Maybe the JS can also be reduced more.

Comment: @Aufziehvogel I've reduced most of the code. Can you assist?

Comment: Can you clarify what actually you want. I mean I dont understand your following example :
I type b then it should sort bbb then abed while not abed then bbb.

Comment: When I type the letter `b` in the search box, the datatable will filter those name containing `b`. I want the datatable to sort the first row by `b` then follow by alphabetical order. Currently it is sorting by default `a-z`